# using my same android application to tablet ,what i can do step by step?

Tags: android

how to let my app support all screens size (smart phones and tablets)  ,so i have all my images in res/drawable-hdpi So do i need to put same images in all drawable folders but with larger size ?? ,what i should do in manifest file ?

```
manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.trysearch"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<supports-screens android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true">
</supports-screens>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/background"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.trysearch.SplashMain"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create different layout files for Mobile phones and tablets. For tablets you should create extra layout folder in res folder which is called layout-large (for tablets), For Mobile phone there is default layout folder, and at the same time for landscape mode you can create one more folder named as layout-large-landscape (tablets) for Mobile phones layout-landscape.

Also in Manisfest file make a change

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Comment: thanks but the better to act my self all layouts for tablet again with the same name of images